# Regex: Allow simple arithmetic using numbers, decimals, and operators [-+*/]

Tags: regex

So, I want to allow numbers with decimals and operators.

This is valid:

```
123*123.333*22-33
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
([0-9]+(\.?[0-9]{1,8})?)+[-+*\/](\1)
```

This doesn't work. I'm guessing because I have the parentheses wrong.

Thoughts?

Comment: What do you want to match or test there?

Comment: @CertainPerformance Essentially, just allow number (with or without decimal) followed by operator `[-+*/]` and then another number (with or without decimal) and then this pattern continued if needed so `num op num op num op num(with decimal)` but not `num op` or `num op num op`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branching off of your original pattern, you might try

```
(\d+(\.\d{1,8})?[-+*\/])+\d+(\.\d{1,8})?
```

where

```
\d+(\.\d{1,8})?
```

matches a number - in simpler language, the regex is

```
(num[-+*\/])+num
```

A number followed by an operator, repeating, followed by a final number.

https://regex101.com/r/itCaQ9/1

Comment: For some reason, this regex doesn't work with '0.136222910*22+22+33'

Comment: Your original regex had a limitation of 8 decimal places, so that's what i copied - the string in your comment has 9 decimal places. If you don't *need* a limit, just use `+` instead. `(\d+(\.\d+)?[-+*\/])+\d+(\.\d+)?`